# May someone convert following linq query syntax into method syntax using lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
        new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18, StandardID = 1 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 21, StandardID = 1 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 18, StandardID = 2 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20, StandardID = 2 } ,
            new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 21 } 
    };

    IList<Standard> standardList = new List<Standard>() { 
        new Standard(){ StandardID = 1, StandardName="Standard 1"},
        new Standard(){ StandardID = 2, StandardName="Standard 2"},
        new Standard(){ StandardID = 3, StandardName="Standard 3"}
    };

    var studentsWithStandard = from stad in standardList
                       join s in studentList
                       on stad.StandardID equals s.StandardID
                       into sg
                           from std_grp in sg 
                           orderby stad.StandardName, std_grp.StudentName 
                           select new { 
                                            StudentName = std_grp.StudentName, 
                                            StandardName = stad.StandardName 
                            };

foreach (var group in studentsWithStandard)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is in {1}", group.StudentName, group.StandardName);
    }
```

i tried. my code is following.

```
 var studentsWithStandard  = standardList.GroupJoin(studentList, stand => stand.StandardID, s => s.StandardID,
            (stand, students) => new {StandardName = stand.StandardName, studentGroup = students}).OrderBy(an => an.StandardName);
```

output will be like this:

```
John is in Standard 1
Steve is in Standard 1
Bill is in Standard 2
Ram is in Standard 2
```

i got it from http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/codeeditor?cid=cs-JUmITE
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want to convert a readable LINQ query into a not readable? With `Join` i definitely prefer query syntax

Comment: I do not get answers. Only get negative votes. Is asking a question crime? Why am I getting negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate the query like this:

```
var ans = standardList.Join(studentList, stad => stad.StandardID, s => s.StandardID, (stad, s) => new { stad, s })
                      .OrderBy(stads => stads.stad.StandardName).ThenBy(stads => stads.s.StudentName)
                      .Select(stads => new { stads.s.StudentName, stads.stad.StandardName });
```

Note that @JamesFaix's answer provides a more efficient less literal version that combines the `Join` and `Select`.

Which is actually the query comprehension version without `into` which isn't needed for your query:

```
var studentsWithStandard = from stad in standardList
                           join s in studentList on stad.StandardID equals s.StandardID
                           orderby stad.StandardName, s.StudentName
                           select new {
                               StudentName = s.StudentName,
                               StandardName = stad.StandardName
                           };
```

Note a strict translation of your query would involve `GroupJoin`/`SelectMany` but it isn't necessary since you aren't try to do a left join:

```
var ans2 = standardList.GroupJoin(studentList, stad => stad.StandardID, s => s.StandardID, (stad, sg) => new { stad, sg })
                       .SelectMany(stadsg => stadsg.sg.Select(s => new { stadsg.stad, s }))
                       .OrderBy(stads => stads.stad.StandardName).ThenBy(stads => stads.s.StudentName)
                       .Select(stads => new { stads.s.StudentName, stads.stad.StandardName });
```

Answer (score 3):

In my experience `join` is the one place where query syntax is more readable than lambda syntax, but regardless...

I would highly recommend reading Jon Skeet's excellent book C# In Depth. The chapters on LINQ give very clear explanations of what various query syntaxes translate to. https://www.manning.com/books/c-sharp-in-depth-third-edition

A `join` expression that only has one `from` will translate to the `Join` method, not `GroupJoin`.  `GroupJoin` is used when you have two `from`s before the `join`.

You would want this to do an inner join:

```
standardList
    .Join(studentList,
        stad => stad.StandardID,
        s => s.StandardID,
        (stad, s) => new { Standard = stad, Student = s })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Standard.StandardName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Student.StudentName)
```

Comment: He has two `from` in his query, but it isn't needed to get his answer. You also left off the `Select`.

Comment: The last parameter of Join basically is a Select

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that. Nice!